# How to find decimal number in a text string in excel with other numbers in the same string

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

For example,

```
 cmn_writeProfileItem(1,"AXIS_DIST",319.2761477779271)
```

I want to only extract 319.2761477, the formula's I've tried will only find 1 in the text string.

EDIT: The decimal value is always the third and final value of in the parenthesis.

Comment: In your data is the decimal value always the third value (and final value) in the brackets, knowing this will help people create a formula that will work for you. Please edit your question with the additional information.

Comment: Extensive examples of advanced searching / matching with regex'es -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops - LibreOffice Calc as `REGEX()`

Answer (score 1):

To return the first non-integer number in the string you can use `FILTERXML` with an `xPath` that filters out the non-decimal numbers:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",","),")",","),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[floor(number(.)) != number(.) and number(.)=number(.)]")
```

This will return the entire number and not just to seven decimals.

***to create the `xml`:***

```
"<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",","),")",","),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>"
```

***xpath argument***

```
"//s[floor(number(.)) != number(.) and number(.)=number(.)]"
```

If you really want the value truncated at the 7th decimal, you will need to do some math functions also.

**edit**

If your pattern is always the same, with the desired value being the last comma separated value followed by a single parenthesis, you can also try:

```
=LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),99)),LEN(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),99)))-1)
```

That will return a text string.

To return a numeric value:

```
=--LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),99)),LEN(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),99)))-1)
```

and just seven decimals:

```
=TRUNC(--LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),99)),LEN(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),99)))-1),7)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern is always the same, maybe use:

```
=TRUNC(--SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)+1,LEN(A1)),")",""),7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Filterxml** function to extract the 3rd and final value in the parenthesis :

Put this formula in `B1`,

```
=TRUNC(-FILTERXML("<a><b>" &SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>(")&"</b></a>","//b[3]"),7)
```

[image]

Or,

Using **Lookup** function to extract the final value in the parenthesis :

```
=TRUNC(-LOOKUP(1,--RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","("),ROW($1:$99))),7)
```